# rxjs rate limit (requests per second) and concurrency

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to figure out how to write a rate limiter in rxjs. Used to access most apis (twitter, facebook, etc) If not supported by out of the box methods, i would assume a scheduler could be written. For instance highland.js has [ratelimit](http://highlandjs.org/#ratelimit). I don't want to drop any items like with window, sample, etc.

```
var source = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {

  // queue of requests
  _.each(requests, function(r) {
    observer.onNext(r);
  });

  observer.onCompleted();

  // Any cleanup logic might go here
  return function () {
    console.log('disposed');
  }
})
  // what goes here, if built in (e.g. 2 requests per 2 seconds or 15 request per 15 minutes)

// SHOULD ONLY RUN
var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) { console.log('onNext: %s', x); },
  function (e) { console.log('onError: %s', e); },
  function () { console.log('onCompleted'); });
```

EDIT 1:
Thinking about something like this, using the token bucket algorithm, still really rough but...

```js
Rx.Observable.prototype.tokenBucket = function(options, scheduler) {
  function time() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  }

  var BUCKET = {
    capacity: options.capacity || Infinity,
    left: options.capacity,
    last: time(),

    tokensPerInterval: options.tokensPerInterval,
    interval: options.interval
  };

  //var BUCKET = _.merge(defaultOptions, options);
  console.log(BUCKET);

  var source = this,
    scheduler = scheduler || (scheduler = Rx.Scheduler.timeout);

  return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    var d1 = source.subscribe(function(mainValue) {
      return throttle(mainValue);
    });

    function throttle(x, tokens) {
      if (BUCKET.capacity === Infinity) {
        return observer.onNext(x);
      } // return x;

      // the number of tokens to add every S milliseconds = (r*S)/1000.
      var self = BUCKET;
      var now = time();

      var deltaMS = Math.max(now - self.last, 0);
      self.last = now;
      var dripAmount = deltaMS * (self.tokensPerInterval / self.interval);
      self.left = Math.min(self.left + dripAmount, self.capacity);

      if (self.left < 1) {
        var interval = Math.ceil((1 - self.left) * self.interval);
        scheduler.scheduleWithRelative(interval, function (s, i) {
          return throttle(x);
        });
      } else {
        self.left -= tokens || 1;
        console.log('calling');
        return observer.onNext(x);
      }
    }

    return function() {
      d1.dispose();
      console.log('disposed tokenBucket');
    };
  });
};

var start = moment();
var source = Rx.Observable.range(1, 20)
  .tokenBucket({capacity: 2, tokensPerInterval: 2, interval: 2000})

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) { console.log('onNext: %s', x); addToDom(x); },
  function (e) { console.log('onError: %s', e); },
  function () { console.log('onCompleted'); });

function addToDom(x) {
  var ul = document.getElementById('c');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = x + ' - ' + moment().diff(start, 'seconds') + 's ago';
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.3/rx.all.js"></script>
<ul id="c"></ul>
```

Comment: You can use buffer/bufferwithtime/bufferwithcount/bufferwithtimeorcount (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/buffer.md)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to drop the events that occur in between you can use windowWithTimeOrCount + throttleFirst:

```
var subscription = source

 //Splits the events into 15 minute windows
 .windowWithTimeOrCount(900000 /*15 minutes*/, 15) 

 //Stops us from receiving more than one window in 15 minutes
 .throttleFirst(900000 /*15 minutes*/)

 //Flatten the observable
 .concatAll()
 .subscribe(
  function (x) { console.log('onNext: %s', x); },
  function (e) { console.log('onError: %s', e); },
  function () { console.log('onCompleted'); });
```

Working example (output in console):

```js
var source = Rx.Observable.generateWithRelativeTime(
    0,
    function(x) { return x < 1000; },
    function(x) { return x + 1; },
    function(x) { return x; },
    function(x) { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); });


source
 .windowWithTimeOrCount(1000, 3)
 .throttleFirst(1000)
 .concatAll()
 .subscribe(console.log.bind(console));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.3/rx.all.js"></script>
```

**Alternative 1**

If you don't want to drop any values you can also use `controlled` on your pipeline along with a specially rolled `regulate` method:

```
var subscription = source
  .windowWithTimeOrCount(900000, 15)
  //This will stop the loss of any events from the hot window
  .map(function(x) {
    var c = x.replay(),
        d = c.connect();
    //Shut down the connected observable when you are done.
    return Rx.Observable.using(function() {return d; },
                               function() {return c; });
  })
  //This will prevent more than one window from going through per interval
  //[See snippet]
  .regulate(900000)
  .concatAll()
  .subscribe(
    function (x) { console.log('onNext: %s', x); },
    function (e) { console.log('onError: %s', e); },
    function () { console.log('onCompleted'); });
```

Working example (output in console):

```js
Rx.Observable.prototype.regulate = function(interval, scheduler) {
  var source = this,
    scheduler = scheduler || (scheduler = Rx.Scheduler.timeout);

  return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
    var controller = source.controlled(scheduler),
      d = new Rx.SerialDisposable();

    function nextSample(x) {

      //This will request a new value after our minimum interval expires
      d.setDisposable(scheduler.scheduleWithRelative(interval, function(s) {
        return controller.request(1);
      }));

      observer.onNext(x);
    }

    return new Rx.CompositeDisposable(
      d,
      controller.subscribe(nextSample,
        observer.onError.bind(observer),
        observer.onCompleted.bind(observer)),
      controller.request(1));

  }, source);

};


var subscription = Rx.Observable.generateWithRelativeTime(
    0,
    function(x) {
      return x < 100;
    },
    function(x) {
      return x + 1;
    },
    function(x) {
      return x;
    },
    function(x) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    })
  //Divides up windows by count and our interval time
  .windowWithTimeOrCount(2000, 15)
  //Necessary since the windows we receive are hot
  .map(function(x) {
    var c = x.replay();
    var d = c.connect();
    return Rx.Observable.using(function() {
      return d;
    }, function() {
      return c;
    });
  })
  //Only allows one window through every 2 seconds
  .regulate(2000)
  //Flatten everything out
  .concatAll()
  .subscribe(console.log.bind(console), console.error.bind(console), console.log.bind(console, "Finished!"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/2.5.3/rx.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am just looking at `generateWithRelativeTime` now. I don't want to drop any in the processing queue. Really just want to prevent from going over the rate limit of the particular api.

Comment: You could also look at `controlled` if you don't want to drop any elements.

Comment: @dre, if you don't want to drop any events, what do you want to do with the extras? Wait for the next opening? Depending on your next application that might start to stack up. Or are you just pinging the endpoint at a certain interval?

Comment: yes, basically a processing queue, so you don't want to drop anything, but you do have to adhere to the rate limits.

Comment: @dre see my alternative. I think it may be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks @paulpdaniels,  i am checking it out now, i was wondering what you think about my token bucket example.

Comment: @dre It certainly appears viable as a solution, it seems a little verbose though so I would be a little concerned about maintainability, but I'm biased :) . There are a couple cases you are missing, i.e. You don't actually handle errors or completion, you can use `scheduler.now()` instead of your own `time` function, and you don't capture the return from `scheduleWithRelative` in case the subscription is disposed

Comment: is there an easy way to do what you are describing, i was trying to come up with an extensible way that could be used dynamically as well, if calls required more than a single token, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've faced a very similar issue in my personal project and decided to publish a reusable solution as a npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-op-lossless-throttle

Unlike http://www.g9labs.com/2016/03/21/lossless-rate-limiting-with-rxjs/ it doesn't force the delay on every single event.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to lose any notification you can use buffer or one of it's variations (with time/count/time or count).
It basically combines the notifications in an array and forwards the array when:

- an observable notifies
- a timer expires
- the count of notifications has been reached
- a combination of the above.

So you could buffer your notifications in an array and receive it only once per minute, or when 100 notifications have arrived.

- [buffer](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/buffer.md)
- [buffer with count](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/bufferwithcount.md)
- [buffer with time](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/bufferwithtime.md)
- [buffer with time or count](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/bufferwithtimeorcount.md)

Comment: This would only let you process items after each buffer is closed. You would not be able to process items as they come it. Also by itself it cannot solve the problem, since the buffers would either be too big, or come in too fast.

Comment: Isn't this what he wants? Maybe I didn't understand.

Comment: No sweat. Based on the original question, the OP was looking for a way to not violate rate limits on a particular endpoint. So for instance if the rate limit were 15 requests over a 15 minute period, `buffer` would either wait until the end of the 15 minutes before emitting (not desirable) or it would emit when it filled, and then start processing the next buffer, which could potentially fire before the end of the 15 minutes (and violate the rate limit).

Comment: yes, this is really the otherside of the coin. Very useful method, just i don't see it helpful for this, maybe I am missing something, an example would clarify things either way.