# RxJS: Send x requests per second

Tags: javascript, http, asynchronous, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have function `createEvent()` which sends a request to google calendar.

Google Calendar's API requires me to send at max 5 requests per second.

If I call `createEvent()` 100 times it will flood google calendar and my requests are denied. If possible I would like `createEvent()` to contain the logic required to throttle requests to 5 per second.

I'm trying to avoid,

```
calendar.addEventToQueue(eventData);
calendar.addEventToQueue(eventData);
calendar.addEventToQueue(eventData);
cleandar.submitEvents();
```

and instead just

```
calendar.createEvent(eventData);
calendar.createEvent(eventData);
calendar.createEvent(eventData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I gave this answer a while back on [rate limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30877526/2521865).

You can do it with RxJS:

```
//This would be replaced by whatever your event source was
//I just made it a button click in this case
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($button, 'click')

  //Captures either all the events for one second for a max of 5 events
  //Projects each set into an Observable
  .windowWithTimeOrCount(1000, 5)

  //Only the first window in a single second gets propagated
  //The others will be dropped
  .throttleFirst(1000)

  //Flatten the sequence by concatenating all the windows
  .concatAll()

  //Build the event body now *after* we have done filtering
  .flatMap(function() { 
    //The calendar request api supports promises which are 
    //handled implicitly in Rx by operators like flatMap. As a result
    //this will automatically wait until it receives a response.
    return gapi.client.calendar.events.insert(/*event body*/);
  });

//Process the response
source.subscribe(
  function(response) { console.log('Event successfully created!'); });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, this is really helpful. Question, `throttleFirst` does not exist in `requrie('rx')` in node. Any recommendations?

Comment: Forgot it was [deprecated](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/928) in 3.1.2. Now it is just called `throttle`.

Comment: Thanks @paulpdaniels, my event source is a stream of event requests. Which should be buffered (delayed) if they exceeded 5 per second `throttle`, seems to be dropping the extra events and only keeping the first output.

Comment: @DanielRasmuson You will need to use a backpressure operator instead of throttle than. In the link I provided I also suggested a way to implement regulate as well.